# Registration form using spring framework

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jakarta-ee, spring-security

I am trying to create registration page using spring,Hibernate and Mysql. 
I can successfully register user information (Save user data using Controller, Services,Dao and Domain classes). 
I want to retrive that user using email and password which he/she entered while registration.
How do i have to write query in spring-security.xml to get username and password.

```
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
        xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.0.3.xsd">

        <http auto-config="true">
            <intercept-url pattern="/welcome*" access="ROLE_USER" />
            <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/welcome"
                authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed" />
            <logout logout-success-url="/logout" />
        </http>

        <authentication-manager>
            <authentication-provider>
                <user-service>

                    <user name="testuser" password="testuser" authorities="ROLE_USER" />
     </user-service>
            </authentication-provider>
        </authentication-manager>


    </beans:beans>




@Entity 
@Table(name = "USER_DETAILS")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column (name = "USER_ID")
    private int id;

    @Column (name = "EMAIL")
    private String email;

    @Column (name = "PASSWORD")
    private String password;

    @Column (name = "FIRST_NAME")
    private String firstName;

    @Column (name = "LAST_NAME")
    private String lastname;

    @Column (name = "ADDRESS")
    private String address;


    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }
    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }
    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }
    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }
    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }
    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }
    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }
    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }
    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }
    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }



}
```

Comment: You need to write a Custom UserDetailsService implementation. Please look at this post http://howtodoinjava.com/2013/04/16/custom-userdetailsservice-example-for-spring-3-security/

Answer (score 1):

You a few options here are 2:

1. Use jdbc-user-service tag in authentication-provider;

This allows you to specify a datasource and run queries to retrieve your user details. The reference is below which shows you what you can and cannot add to the tag.

This seems to be the right option for you as you want to place the query in the xml.

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/appendix-namespace.html#nsa-jdbc-user-service

Example:

```
<authentication-manager>
  <authentication-provider>
    <jdbc-user-service data-source-ref="securityDataSource"/>
  </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

A complete example can be found here: http://www.raistudies.com/spring-security-tutorial/authentication-authorization-spring-security-mysql-database/

1. Create a custom user details service;

This allows you to provide your own implementation of the **UserDetailsService**. The reference to the spring doc is below.

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.1.4.RELEASE/reference/technical-overview.html#tech-userdetailsservice

Answer (score 0):

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<meta>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Customer Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/form}" th:object="${customer}" method="post">

    <p>First Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{firstname}" /></p>
    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{lastname}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    <br>
    <a href="vewall">Viewall</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>SUBMIT SUCCESSFUL</h1>
<a href="/form">Submit another Customer Form</a>

</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<meta>
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Update</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/update/{id}(id=${user.id})}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <label for="fname">Name</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{firstname}" id="fname" placeholder="Name">

    <label for="lname">Email</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{lastname}" id="lname" placeholder="Email">

    <input type="submit" value="Update User">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>List of cities</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>FName</th>
        <th>LName</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>

    <tr th:each="city : ${cus}">
        <td th:text="${city.id}">Id</td>
        <td th:text="${city.firstname}">Name</td>
        <td th:text="${city.lastname}">Population</td>
        <td><a th:href="@{/update/{id}(id=${city.id})}">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id=${city.id})}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

package com.form.demo.model;

import javax.persistence.*;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Objects;

@Entity
@Table(name = "cust1")
public class Customer implements Serializable {
    @Id
  //  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)

    private long id;

    @Column(name = "firstname")

    private String firstname;
    @Column(name = "lastname")

    private String lastname;

    public Customer() {
        this.firstname = firstname;
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstname() {
        return firstname;
    }

    public void setFirstname(String firstname) {
        this.firstname = firstname;
    }

    public String getLastname() {
        return lastname;
    }

    public void setLastname(String lastname) {
        this.lastname = lastname;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (o == null || getClass() != o.getClass()) return false;
        Customer customer = (Customer) o;
        return id == customer.id &&
                Objects.equals(firstname, customer.firstname) &&
                Objects.equals(lastname, customer.lastname);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {

        return Objects.hash(id, firstname, lastname);
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Customer{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", firstname='" + firstname + '\'' +
                ", lastname='" + lastname + '\'' +
                '}';
    }
}
package com.form.demo.Repo;


import com.form.demo.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;



public interface CustoRepo extends CrudRepository<Customer,Long> {


}

package com.form.demo.Serv;



import com.form.demo.model.Customer;

import java.util.List;

public interface CustoSevice  {

public List<Customer> findAll();
public Customer findById(Long id);
public void delete(Customer customer);

void save(Customer customer);
}

package com.form.demo.Serv;


import com.form.demo.Repo.CustoRepo;
import com.form.demo.model.Customer;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.List;
@Service
public class CustoServiceIml implements CustoSevice {

    private CustoRepo custoRepo;

    public CustoServiceIml(CustoRepo custoRepo) {
        this.custoRepo = custoRepo;
    }

    @Override
    public List<Customer> findAll() {
        List<Customer> customers= (List<Customer>) custoRepo.findAll();

        return customers;
    }

    @Override
    public Customer findById(Long id) {
        Customer customer=custoRepo.findById(id).orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid user Id:" + id));
        return customer;
    }

    @Override
    public void delete(Customer customer) {
        custoRepo.delete(customer);
    }


    @Override
    public void save(Customer customer) {
        custoRepo.save(customer);
    }


}

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/new1
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=root
```

Comment: You should add some description not just paste the code.

Answer (score -1):

```
<html lang="en"  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">


meta>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Customer Form</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/form}" th:object="${customer}" method="post">

    <p>First Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{firstname}" /></p>
    <p>Last Name: <input type="text" th:field="*{lastname}" /></p>
    <p><input type="submit" value="Submit" /> <input type="reset" value="Reset" /></p>
    <br>
    <a href="vewall">Viewall</a>
</form>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

<h1>SUBMIT SUCCESSFUL</h1>
<a href="/form">Submit another Customer Form</a>

</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"  xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<meta>
<meta charset="UTF-8"></meta>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Update</h1>
<form action="#" th:action="@{/update/{id}(id=${user.id})}" th:object="${user}" method="post">
    <label for="fname">Name</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{firstname}" id="fname" placeholder="Name">

    <label for="lname">Email</label>
    <input type="text" th:field="*{lastname}" id="lname" placeholder="Email">

    <input type="submit" value="Update User">
</form>
</body>
</html>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<h2>List of cities</h2>

<table>
    <tr>
        <th>ID</th>
        <th>FName</th>
        <th>LName</th>
        <th>Edit</th>
        <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>

    <tr th:each="city : ${cus}">
        <td th:text="${city.id}">Id</td>
        <td th:text="${city.firstname}">Name</td>
        <td th:text="${city.lastname}">Population</td>
        <td><a th:href="@{/update/{id}(id=${city.id})}">Edit</a></td>
        <td><a th:href="@{/delete/{id}(id=${city.id})}">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>

enter code here
```